# Ajax простой пример

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте я только начал изучать AJAx нашел в сети простой пример потренироваться, но он почему-то не работает, хотя сделал один в один, не могли бы знатоки указать на ошибку и как его исправить до работоспособного состояния?

Файл index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>AJAX</title>
</HEAD>
<boDY>
 <input id="shop_ip" type="button" value="ПОКАЗАТЬ МОЙ IP">
 <div id="myip"></div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Файл script

```html
window.onload=function(){
 document.querySelector("#shop_ip").onclick=function(){
   ajaxGet();
 }
}

function ajaxGet(){
 var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
 
 request.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (request.readyState=4 && request.status=200){
   document.querySelector('#myip').innerHTML=request.responseText;
  }
  
  console.log(request.readyState);
 }
 
 request.open('GET','ip.php');
 request.send();
}
```

Файл ip.php

```html
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Благодарю всех откликнувшихся

Comment: Что у вас в консоле?

Comment: «Не работает» это не описание ошибки. Что именно происходит?

Comment: Ничего не происходит, браузер Mozilla пишет в консоли "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работает: Вы указали присваивание, а нужно сравнение в request.readyState==4 и request.status==200

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AJAX</title>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <input id="shop_ip" type="button" value="ПОКАЗАТЬ МОЙ IP">
        <div id="myip"></div>
        <script>
        window.onload=function(){
        document.querySelector("#shop_ip").onclick=function(){
          ajaxGet();
        }
    }

    function ajaxGet(){
        var request=new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200){
                document.querySelector('#myip').innerHTML=request.responseText;
            }

            console.log(request.readyState);
        }

        request.open('GET','ip.php');
        request.send();
    }</script>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что указали на мою ошибку, все заработало.

Comment: )Пожалуйста, рад!